# How to fix “PG::Error: Wait on socket” error when accessing Postgres DB in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, pg

One of our application is built on Rails 3 which uses postgres as database. We observe that while doing load test i.e continuously submitting request, there are random exceptions related to database
(comes from postgres_adapter):

```
1. PG::Error: Wait on socket error (WaitForMultipleObjects):
2. NoMethodError: undefined method `result_error_field' for nil:NilClass:
```

I am not able to find any reference on cause of these issues as they're coming at different points. Any help on how to avoid this or solve this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What OS version and what Ruby version and what pg gem version and what PostgreSQL version? As a guess, your operating system needs a socket to make the connection and for whatever reason isn't able to provide one in a timely fashion.

Comment: Windows OS. It happens on win7 and win10. Ruby version is 1.9.3p551.

Comment: I wish I could give you a better answer but you’re using an obsolete version of Ruby and of Rails and you’re running them on Windows. I think your best bet is attempting to upgrade to more modern versions or switching to Linux.

Comment: For now it may be difficult to migrate to unix or different version. Any idea what could lead to "PG::Error: Wait on socket error (WaitForMultipleObjects)" error? Could this be because of windows socket not avaulable or Postgres connection not available or something else.